# jQuery stop() messes up text

Tags: jquery

example: http://jsfiddle.net/V4Arr/5/

My goal is to show a text once you hover over the visible text. To protect against animation builtup I used stop() function, but it starts to mess up other elements (and messes up animation too)! You can see how this looks after few hovers on the text.
Any solutions?

```
$(document).ready(
      function () {
         $("#cont").hover(
             function () {
               $("#secret").stop().show("slide", "350");
            }, 
             function () {
               $("#secret").stop().hide("slide");
            }
          );
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.stop` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) accepts two arguments:

> `clearQueue`
>       Type: Boolean
>       A Boolean indicating whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to `false`.
>
> `jumpToEnd`
>       Type: Boolean
>       A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately. Defaults to `false`.

Use:

```
.stop(true, true)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cont").hover(function () {
        $("#secret").stop(true, true).show("slide", "350");
    }, function () {
        $("#secret").stop(true, true).hide("slide");
    }
  );
});
```